# Microsoft Edge Browser Disappeared after Anniversary Update

Tags: windows-10-v1607, microsoft-edge

My Edge browser has disappeared after installing the Windows 10 Anniversary Update.  I have tried all suggestions (including the power shell command), and nothing will work to reinstall it.  As a note, the Microsoft Edge folder is missing in the packages folder, so I cannot delete it to re-install edge.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Roll back to version 1511.  If your running an enterprise version of Windows your administrator might have removed it.

Comment: Thanks David, I didn't know how to reply to a post, so I am using this method.  I couldn't roll back because I surpassed the 10 day limit.  I appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the Edge Browser back, by copying an Edge shortcut from a working system to the working system's desktop.  Then I copied that shortcut to the desktop to the non-working system.  As soon as I clicked the copied shortcut on the non-working system, Edge came back and showed in the start menu again.